# Tarantool wal config

Tags: tarantool

We are using Tarantool 1.5 and have question with config options: if we set following options:

```
wal_fsync_delay=2
wal_mode=write
```

Does it mean fsync(2) will not be called at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means sync every two seconds. I don't recommend this set up, we removed it in 1.6 - it leads to latency spikes, sine Linux filesystem makes fsync performance totally unpredictable.